# Baseball Projectile Motion

Tags: vectors, physics, projectile-motion

> A baseball batter can hit the ball at an angle between $45°$ and $60°$. At all angles, the initial speed is $30$m/s. There are two catchers, catcher $A$ can run at $5$m/s and catcher $B$ can run at $2.5$m/s. How far should each catcher stand from the batter so they can catch the ball wherever it lands? Assume $g=9.8$ and that this all takes place in just two dimensions.

My attempt: Using projectile motion vectors, I could find where the ball landed at $45°$ and $60°$, but didn’t know what to in the second part of the question using the speeds of the catchers.

Comment: Well, you know where the ball landed and when it landed, so you know how much time the catcher has to get there. Since you know the speed of the catcher, you know the distance he covered to get to the ball. So your answer is the difference between the distance from the batter to the point where the ball lands and the distance covered by the catcher to get to the ball.

Comment: It depends at which height the ball is released.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe when nothing has been said, we must assume that the ball is thrown from the ground